# How to register with Django admin approval?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In the system I created with Django, users should not log in without the admin approval after registration. For example, after the user fills in the registration form, user will see the warning

> waiting for admin approval

and cannot login to the system without approval from the admin panel.

*views.py*

```
def signup(request):

    form_class = SignUpForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            user.first_name = form.data['first_name']
            user.last_name = form.data['last_name']
            user.rank = form.data['rank']
            user.comp_name = form.data['comp_name']
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = form_class()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

*models.py*

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    ranks = (
        ('analyst', 'Analyst'),
        ...
    )
    comp_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="Choose")
    user_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4(), editable=False, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=ranks)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you are using a custom user model based on the built-in abstract model. The `AbstractUser` model has a field named `is_active` which you can use here.

During the registration process, set the value for `is_active` to `False` and use the default `AuthenticationForm` form for the login view. This form will automatically check for the `is_active` flag and provide an error when it is `False`.

Default error messages (you can customize them):

```py
error_messages = {
    'invalid_login': _(
        "Please enter a correct %(username)s and password. Note that both "
        "fields may be case-sensitive."
    ),
    'inactive': _("This account is inactive."),
}
```

You can get the form from the `auth` package:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
```

In your custom admin for the `UserProfile` model add a filter for the `is_active` flag:

```py
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filters = ["is_active"]
```

That way, you will be able to list non-active profiles and activate them in the admin.

Comment: Where should I add the error_messages section in my code?

Comment: If you don't want to use the default error messages provided in the form, best way would be to create your own `AuthenticationForm` form using this one as a base (`MyAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):`) and provide your own error messages (with the same format as `error_messages` dictionary from the answer).